# Function that takes 3 list arguments and returns all the combinations

Tags: python, function

I need help coming up with a function in Python that takes 3 arguments that are lists and can return all the combinations.

For example, if I ran:

```
shirts = ['white', 'blue']
ties = ['purple', 'yellow']
suits = ['grey', 'blue']
combinations = dress_me(shirts, ties, suits)
for combo in combinations:
    print combo
```

It would print something like:

```
('white', 'purple', 'grey')
('white', 'purple', 'blue')
('white', 'yellow', 'grey')
('white', 'yellow', 'blue')
('blue', 'purple', 'grey')
('blue', 'purple', 'blue')
('blue', 'yellow', 'grey')
('blue', 'yellow', 'blue')
```

Comment: I think what I have answered is right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. In general, avoid trying to write your entire question in the title.

Comment: @Jonathan : I hate when some nerds will downvote this post , I mean this guy is new , give him some break -- no you have to read 40 page of EULA , and then post here .

Comment: Nobody downvoted it though actually it deserves it. The OP has just posted a same question. I and some others have answered it. If he is not satisfied with the answers. He may comments edit.@MotiurRahman

Answer (score 6):

[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to the rescue.

```
import itertools

def dress_me(*choices):
  return itertools.product(*choices)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def dress_me(l1, l2, l3):
    return [(i, j, k) for i in l1 for j in l2 for k in l3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dress_me(l1, l2, l3):
    res = []
    for i in l1:
        for j in l2:
            for k in l3:
                res.append((i, j, k))
    return res

shirts = ['white', 'blue']
ties = ['purple', 'yellow']
suits = ['grey', 'blue']

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    combinations = dress_me(shirts, ties, suits)
    for combo in combinations:
        print(combo)
```